# cannot insert path file address to mysql using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i have problem to insert this text to mysql in vb.net

```
C:\Users\Riski\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Remainder\Remainder\images\activ\
```

and this my source for insert

```
 Try
                Dim tbimg As String
                tbimg = tbimgpath.text
                'Prepare Connection and Query
                dbconn = New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=team;Uid=root;Pwd=")

                'OPEN THE DB AND KICKOFF THE QUERY
                dbconn.Open()
                DS = New DataSet
                DA = New MySqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO tb_team_user (id_team_user,user_ip,user_team,user_image_path) values (null,'" & lip.Text & "','" & tbteam.Text & "','" & tbimg & "')", dbconn)
                DA.Fill(DS, "tb_info_activity")

                'DONE CLOSE THE DB
                dbconn.Close()

                Application.Restart()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("cannot connect to database!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
            End Try
```

if i write without symbol '\' and ':' the insert work fine but if i write with symbol and the insert give me warning just "check the manual that corresponds"

how resolve this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use string concatenation to build your sql query. Otherwise you are open for sql injection and other issues like this. The backslash introduces [escape characters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-literals.html) like `\r` for carriage return. So just use sql-parameters with the correct types:

```
Using dbconn = New MySqlConnection("connectionstring")
    Dim insertSql = "INSERT INTO tb_team_user (id_team_user,user_ip,user_team,user_image_path)" & _
                    "VALUES (null,@user_ip,@user_team,@user_image_path)"
    Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter()
        da.InsertCommand = New MySqlCommand(insertSql, dbconn)
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@user_ip", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Int32.Parse(lip.Text)
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@user_team", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbteam.Text
        da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@user_image_path", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbimg.Text
        ' .. '
    End Using
End Using
```

Apart from that, why do you use an `INSERT`-sql for `DataAdaper.Fill`? You need a `Select`.

So maybe you want to use `MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` instead:

```
Using dbconn = New MySqlConnection("connectionstring")
    Dim insertSql = "INSERT INTO tb_team_user (id_team_user,user_ip,user_team,user_image_path)" & _
                    "VALUES (null,@user_ip,@user_team,@user_image_path)"
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(insertSql, dbconn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@user_ip", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = Int32.Parse(lip.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@user_team", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbteam.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@user_image_path", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbimg.Text
        dbconn.Open()
        Dim insertedCount As Int32 = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: sorry, I'm just a beginner so still less neatly makes the code, I've tried to follow the code that you gave but I get a warning: refrerence object not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @RiskiFebriansyah: i have edited the first part of my answer with the `MySqlDataAdapter`. But i'm fairly sure that you need the second. You cannot use `DA.Fill` without a `SelectCommand`.